# Error installing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following Java version installed: "**Version 7** Update 9" in **Windows 7 64-bit**, in the "**Program files (x86)**" folder.
I think this came by default when I installed Windows.

I am now trying to install Eclipse for Win 64 Bit using this link: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-win32-x86_64.zip

But I get an error when I launch Exclipse.exe:
[image]

Is this related to the fact Java is installed in the "Program Files x86" folder on a Win 64 bit? How can I solve this so I can install Eclipse? 
By the way, Java should work fine, I've opened some applet demo samples in the IE browser, all good.

Last time I installed Eclipse on another PC went fine, I'm guessing the system configuration has to do with this error in this case. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the JRE/JDK on the WINDOWS path.  This can be done by opening up the environment variables option in Windows.  The error you receive is because java isn't on that path so eclipse defaults to its location.

Answer (score 2):

4 possible fix:

1. set java home path
2. install 32 bit jdk version 6.
3. start eclipse using something similar eclipse -vm c:\jdk1.4.2\jre\bin\javaw
4. start eclipse using     eclipse -clean    and set java settings accordingly.
   for more information look @ here http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm

Comment: I think you mean install the 64 bit JDK, as he already has the 32 bit JDK installed.

Comment: I had the same error, in my case it was all 64bit, and the solution was to install 32bit java. and yes he has already installed 32bit jdk but not version 6.

Comment: That is if you use the 32 bit Eclipse on 64 bit windows, but given the name of his Eclipse (`x86_64`), I would think he has installed the 64 bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the java folder existed on disk but not in registry. It maybe a leftover of previous installation. Try installing 32 bit eclipse or installing 64 bit java.

Simpler fix

Copy the java folder to the eclipse installation and rename it to `jre`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the advice.

It finally worked after I did the following:

- I installed the JDK 7 for Win 64
- I set the variable Path like this: 
  System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables -> Path -> Edit: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin
- I copied the Eclipse structure (after unzipping) to Program files
- I launched Eclipse.exe, configured workspace, etc.

Now I can start using Eclipse to create packages, classes, applets etc.

Comment: You need to mark this as the answer if it is.  StackOverflow is not a traditional forum

Comment: done, selected yours! Too bad I can't mark all. All were useful. Thanks!